# Mail client continues to use old MX record after TTL expired; authoritative entry missing

Tags: email, mx-record, nslookup

I changed MX records at my domain name provider (network solutions) twice today. One test client is still sending mails to the older record even though its TTL has expired. So, in other words, this is what happened:

1. Changed MX records to point to messagingengine.com at 10 AM
   (did not send any test mails via this server)
2. Changed MX records to point to zoho.com at 11:30 AM
3. At 1pm test emails from most client work via zoho, but 1 client that is using Microsoft Exchange still trying to send to messagingengine.com
4. At 2:30 pm test emails from the MS Exchange client STILL trying to go to messagingengine.com

The TTL for messagingengine.com is 1 hour, so it is long expired.

However, when I do an NSLOOKUP, it gives the non-authoritative answer correctly as zoho, but gives no authoritative entry. It is just blank. In other words, the nslookup says "Authoritative answers can be found from:" and then nothing. Here is what it looks like (identifiers redacted):

[image: nslookup failure]

I think the problem must be that the record maintained by Network Solutions is somehow defective so that it is not identifying itself as the authoritative server somehow.

What really mystifies me is how the MS Exchange client could have gotten the messagingengine.com domain, since I did not send any test emails during the (short period) that my DNS records was pointing to that domain.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: As long as you are sure you entered your details right stop trying to change the entry and let it finish.. Pretty much every one of those registrars that provides DNS takes _forever_ to get everything updated. For the minimal price ($50 a year if you look) a dedicated DNS service is one of the best investments you can make.

Comment: If you're running nslookup against your own DNS server (meaning not against the authoritative name server for the domain) then a non-authoritative answer is what I would expect. Your DNS server can't answer authoritatively for a domain that it isn't authoritative for. I think that's confusing you a bit.

Comment: @joeqwerty Normally NSLOOKUP will give both the authoritative answer and then list the server where the authoritative answer can be obtained. That is not happening. The authoritative information is blank.

Comment: What does your nslookup query look like? Can you post it in your question?

Comment: @joeqwerty I have edited my question to include a screen shot of the nslookup MX query results

Comment: OK. That's not a Windows client you're running nslookup from. If it is, it's one I've never seen before. That explains why we're talking different languages to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running nslookup against your own DNS server (meaning not against the authoritative name server for the domain) then a non-authoritative answer is what I would expect. Your DNS server can't answer authoritatively for a domain that it isn't authoritative for.

`@joeqwerty Normally NSLOOKUP will give both the authoritative answer and then list the server where the authoritative answer can be obtained. That is not happening. The authoritative information is blank`

I see 0 authoritative answers in this query.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator
Default Server:  MyDnsServer
Address:  x.x.x.x

> set debug
> yahoo.com.
Server:  myDnsServer
Address:  x.x.x.x

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 3,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        yahoo.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  yahoo.com
        internet address = 98.138.253.109
        ttl = 1173 (19 mins 33 secs)
    ->  yahoo.com
        internet address = 206.190.36.45
        ttl = 1173 (19 mins 33 secs)
    ->  yahoo.com
        internet address = 98.139.183.24
        ttl = 1173 (19 mins 33 secs)

------------
Non-authoritative answer:
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 3,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        yahoo.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  yahoo.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2001:4998:58:c02::a9
        ttl = 133 (2 mins 13 secs)
    ->  yahoo.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2001:4998:44:204::a7
        ttl = 133 (2 mins 13 secs)
    ->  yahoo.com
        AAAA IPv6 address = 2001:4998:c:a06::2:4008
        ttl = 133 (2 mins 13 secs)

------------
Name:    yahoo.com
Addresses:  2001:4998:58:c02::a9
          2001:4998:44:204::a7
          2001:4998:c:a06::2:4008
          98.138.253.109
          206.190.36.45
          98.139.183.24

>
```

Can you post your nslookup query?